# iphone NSComparisonResult for two NSDecimalNumber objects fails

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

```
NSDecimalNumber *no1    = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[totalPotFund stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."]];//consider totalPotFund = 301
NSLog(@"Total Bank Fund: %@", totalPotFund);

NSDecimalNumber *no2    = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[MinimumFund stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."]];//consider MinimumFund = 1000
NSLog(@"Debet: %@", MinimumFund);

NSDecimalNumber *result = [no1 decimalNumberBySubtracting:no2];//301 - 1000 = -699
NSLog(@"Result = Total Bank Fund - Debet: %@ - %@ = %@", totalPotFund, MinimumFund, result);

NSDecimalNumber *no3  = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[payAmt.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."]];//consider payAmt = 12
NSLog(@"Amount to be paid: %@", payAmt.text);

NSComparisonResult res = [result compare:no3]; //-699 compare 12: -699 < 12

NSLog(@"Compare Resultant Amount with CheckOut Amount: %@ compare %@", result, no3);//

if(res == NSOrderedAscending)
{
    Do Something
}
else
{
    Do The Other Thing
}
```

Hi all, the problem I'm facing is that though -699 is lesser than 12, it still goes in the 
"if(res == NSOrderedAscending)" condition and not the "else" condition. Funny it should be doing that. I haven't got any example code as such for 2 NSDecimal numbers comparison with NSComparisonResult and send the compared result to NSOrderedAscending or NSOrderedDescending or NSOrderedSame.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the apple docs:

> NSOrderedAscending if the value of decimalNumber is greater than the
>   receiver; NSOrderedSame if they’re equal; and NSOrderedDescending if
>   the value of decimalNumber is less than the receiver.

`NSOrderedAscending` is the correct result, since the argument (no3 = 12) is greater than the receiver (result = -699).

Comment: thnx for the answer, but ain't a negative number lesser than a positive number?? when I'm comparing -699 with 12, -699 is smaller than +12, isn't it? I don't understand why iPhone would do such a stupid thing as to not allow proper comparison of a negative number and a positive number. I'd read the docs and so had tried the comparator, but looks like the mad comparator is giving me crap. any help to get me out of frustration would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Yes, -699 is less than 12.  Hence the order is **ascending** when you go from -699 to 12.

Comment: thnx, got it. ur reply was a clue which led me 2 d solution

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully the documentation: NSOrderedAscending is returned if decimalNumber > receiver. In your case receiver=result=-699 and decimalNumber=no3=12 so as decimalNumber>receiver then NSOrderedAscending is returned, as expected.

From Apple docs:

compare:
Returns an NSComparisonResult value that indicates the numerical ordering of the receiver and another given NSDecimalNumber object.

- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSNumber *)decimalNumber
  Parameters
  decimalNumber
  The number with which to compare the receiver.

Return Value
NSOrderedAscending if the value of decimalNumber is greater than the receiver; NSOrderedSame if they’re equal; and NSOrderedDescending if the value of decimalNumber is less than the receiver.

Comment: viggio24: thnx for the answer, but ain't a negative number lesser than a positive number?? when I'm comparing -699 with 12, -699 is smaller than +12, isn't it?
I don't understand why iPhone would do such a stupid thing as to not allow proper comparison of a negative number and a positive number. I'd read the docs and so had tried the comparator, but looks like the mad comparator is giving me crap.
any help to get me out of frustration would be appreciated. 
thanks